# Losing power in the UK vs US: what's more common?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, british-english, transatlantic-differences

Which of the following is more common in British English vs American English?

- Power cut
- Power outage
- Power failure
- Blackout

Comment: Power outage appears to be more common in AmE as shown in Google Books https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=power+outage%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cpower+outage%3Aeng_us_2012&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cpower%20outage%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpower%20outage%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPower%20outage%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cpower%20outage%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpower%20outage%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPower%20Outage%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPower%20outage%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Actually, Google Ngrams shows that *blackout* is by far the most common in both BrE and AmE. This ***might*** be a false positive, because *blackout* has other meanings. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blackout%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cblackout%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cpower+outage%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cpower+cut%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2000).

Comment: Thank you, Peter. But I'd be more grateful if you'd tell me about your own experience of the words. Which one do you use or hear most?

Comment: I hear both *blackout* and *power outage* in AmE, and they're both reasonably common.

Comment: *Power cut* is the usual term in the UK, and the one most commonly used in news bulletins. If a widespread power cut (an entire city, say,) occurs during the night, it might be called a *total blackout* (especially by the more sensational newspapers), since it harks back to the *blackouts* that were enforced during World War 2.

Comment: '...outage' and '... failure' seem to be equally common in the NYC area, anecdotally, but both are less common than 'blackout'. '... cut' is vanishingly rare, and would only be used if it was a deliberate action by the provider.

Comment: If anyone cares, in Canadian English you hear all these terms, but "power cut" is quite uncommon and refers specifically to an intentional interruption in power (e.g. a service disconnection due to cancellation of service or for non-payment). It wouldn't describe an ordinary temporary disruption.

Comment: in the states ... 'the power is out'  or shorter ... powers out.

Comment: The problem is that these are all used in different contexts.  "Power cut" would the least common (in the US) but only because it's mainly reserved for an intentional disconnection.

Comment: Yes, I distinguish between all of these. Power outage is most general; power cut is intentional; blackout happens at (or continues into) nighttime; power failure is usually localized, like in a single building or car or machine.

Comment: Blackout implies a large-scale outage, as when a power plant drops off line or entire grid sections get isolated. It isn't used when a transformer on your street blows. Personally, I don't associate it with daytime or nighttime in any way. I wouldn't use it for outages smaller than 50,000 people. [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blackout) seems to agree. "c : a period of darkness (as in a city) caused by a failure of electrical power"

Comment: In my Br.E experience, while a "power cut" _could_ be intentional, the term doesn't _imply_ intentionality.

Comment: @HotLicks Are not nearly all such blackouts "intentional", in that the system gets shut down either automatically or manually when there is a problem, or overload? So the underlying reason may well be accidental, but the immediate cause is because someone or some computer has thrown a switch. After WW2 in Britain it took a number of years to build up generation capacity to required levels. So it was often the case that there were overloads. Hence the origin of the term "power cut".

Comment: @WS2 - Tripping a breaker to prevent a transformer from exploding may be the intended cause/effect action, but it is not "intentional" in the sense that someone intended the power to go out at 3:06PM.

Comment: @HotLicks I guess what I am saying is that there is no clear distinction between a "blackout" and a "cut" - since both involve an interruption of power. And most times the consumer is "totally in the dark" (excuse the pun) as to what the cause was.

Answer (score 1):

"Power cut" is certainly the most common in the UK, as seen in the comments.  [*Lexico* Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/power_cut) gives the phrase the "British" tag.

On [Google News](https://news.google.com/search?q=%22power%20cut%22&hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen), almost all of the news is UK stories, and it's the same *story* ;-) for [*power outage*](https://news.google.com/search?q=%22power%20outage%22&hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen) in the US.

As for *blackout* being used as a term for a mass outage in the UK, the fairly recent mass power cut that affected the nation is indeed referred to as a [blackout](https://news.google.com/search?q=%20%22uk%20blackout%22%20when%3A1y&hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen) more often than power cut.

"Power outage" is often used to refer to a more local failure, whereas "Power failure" is almost never heard, clearly shown on NGrams:[image: NGRAM1]

"Blackout" is also seemingly used to mean a wide-scale outage in the US, as shown in [News](https://news.google.com/search?q=us%20blackout&hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen) as well.

"Power failure" doesn't seem that popular [either](https://news.google.com/search?q=us%20power%20failure&hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen), and as it's a UK term, "power cut" is close to [nonexistent.](https://news.google.com/search?q=us%20power%20cut&hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen) (where "cut" is used, it's usually published by a UK news site).

Answer (score 0):

I heard "outage" being used in a film set in 1940s England - which led me here. I never heard the term "outage" before this millennium. I have only used and heard "power cut" before, whether the cause was accidental or planned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/415260)

Answer (score -2):

The Google NGrams corpus search on all four, for UK and US separately are shown here:

[image: compare gb/us on all four]

Blackout seems to be by far the most popular in both the UK and US, then 'power failure'. 'Power outage' and 'power cut' both seem to be rare in the US.

Comment: As a Br.E. speaker, this _feels_ wrong ("_power cut_" is the term I'd use/have most often heard). Does this graph exclude, say, _blackout_ used for someone fainting, or _power failure_ used for individual pieces of equipment rather than the whole mains supply failing?

Comment: I think this is misleading; here in the D-M-V I hear *blackout* mainly to reference large-scale grid failures, fainting episodes, spans of lost memory during a night of heavy drinking, or the curtains you vow to install while recovering from that night. If the transformer blows on a street, it's just a *power outage*.

Comment: Context is everything. "Resistance is futile". This thing of looking up single words without taking context into account is a fool's errand, in my opinion.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, that is a problem with any simplistic corpus search.

Comment: @TripeHound No, the search doesn't account for polysemy, it is just searching for the letter sequence. However for 'blackout' in the US at least, a noun is uncommon, you usually say 'I blacked out' rather than 'I had a blackout'.

Comment: @choster 1) what is 'D-M-V'? 2) Thanks for the exxplanation. The OP asked for these four terms, and there's the picture of the data, now we can analyze what it really means. Even if 'blackout' is not the same as 'power outage' etc at least we know relative frequency.

Comment: This is interesting in this context. I just googled "power cut" and "Massachusetts" and the top results included power cut and Massachusetts in The Guardian and the BBC, whereas among those same top "local" results "power cut" became "power outage" and Massachusetts. So, that immediately told me that yes, power cut is indeed BrE. (Well, told me because I know how to "read that"? Dunno). :)

Comment: @Mitch 1. District of Columbia - Maryland - Virginia  2. *Blacked out* would mean passing out to me, not necessarily a level of intoxication. The younger crowd which gets comfortable around me say things like *I'm not surprised she finally hooked up with him; he was blackout drunk*, or *they were wasted that night, but not blackout*; people closer to my own age debate whether to get *blackouts* for the nursery to promote napping.

Comment: @choster there's also 'blackout dates' for times in a schedule that are not allowed to be used, like airlines do for use of frequent flyer miles.

Comment: Maybe redo the Ngram using "power blackout" instead.